# Add arrow to a descriptive diagram with smartdiagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, smartdiagram

I would like to add an arrow to the following diagram.

[image]

The diagram is generated using http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/smart-description/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
\begin{document}
\hspace*{1cm}\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
  {Style,{Define shapes, colors, shading,
          and line styles for nodes and arrows}},
  {Position, {Place nodes using a matrix,
              relative or absolute positioning}},
  {Relation, Insert edges or arrows
             between selected nodes},
  {Label, Add labels on edges or arrows}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]  
\draw[-stealth,line width=1mm,green!40] 
(module-title4.west) to[out=120,in=-120] (module-title1.west);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

What's going on here? `smartdiagram` gives the nodes names which can be inferred from page 5 of the manual:

[image]

With `\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}` one makes sure that these nodes do not get forgotten, and then one can access them with an `overlay` picture and do whatever one likes. Since you are using the `standalone` class and `overlay` does not extend the bounding box, I added `\hspace*{1cm}` to make sure the arrow does not get clipped away. The same strategy has been used [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469980/121799) but without the explanation how one can obtain the node names, simply because back then I got them from the code rather than the manual.